# Seeing which photos I sent to whom on Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I'd like to know what photos, videos, files have I've sent to whom. I notice just after sending something, I see in green above how many photos I've sent to "x" email address, but after the fact, I am not able to find any specific information. To simply see the generic, "shared" doesn't help at all.

Is this feature available, or is it a sorely obvious weak point on the otherwise wonderful Dropbox application? There are so many times I wonder if I've sent something to a person. You can't see it from your sent email.

Comment: There's no guarantee that Dropbox would ever see this "feature request", so I've whittled it down into something that someone could answer within the current set of features.

Answer (score -2):

Try using our application [Orangedox](http://orangedox.com/dropbox), unlike Dropbox you'll be able to create multiple share links for each recipient that you've sent your photos to.  You'll also be able to see when the photo was downloaded or previewed